# pytorch cannot be installed and torch package is not found

Tags: python, windows, pip, pytorch

I'm trying to install pytorch/torch in my windows computer, I tried `pip intall pytorch`

I got the following error:

```bash
C:\Users\mouss>pip install pytorch
Collecting pytorch
  Using cached pytorch-1.0.2.tar.gz (689 bytes)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pytorch
  Building wheel for pytorch (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\mouss\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-re456wuk\pytorch_687632f0314d499d868cb85ed33f83ba\setup.py", line 15, in <module>
          raise Exception(message)
      Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pytorch
  Running setup.py clean for pytorch
Failed to build pytorch
Installing collected packages: pytorch
  Running setup.py install for pytorch ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pytorch did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\mouss\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-re456wuk\pytorch_687632f0314d499d868cb85ed33f83ba\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
          raise Exception(message)
      Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pytorch

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

based on `Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"`,I figured out that it's name changed to `torch`, so I tried `pip install torch`
then I got this error:

```bash
C:\Users\mouss>pip install torch
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
```

do you have any idea how to install pytorch/torch in my computer?

Comment: Go to https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ and follow the instructions to create an installation command. Please be aware that Torch is not currently available for Python 3.11 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question, [pypi](https://pypi.org/) doesn't have PyTorch anymore, so to install it, you need a "special" command may i say

i recommend going to [PyTorch - get started locally](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) to get the command according to your os, package manager, etc...

it would be something like:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
```

hope this helps

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Additionally, this assumes you have CUDA 11.6, which may not be the case.

Comment: @MattDMo thanks for the reminder, i will edit the question right away

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work. output is the same `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)`

Comment: they mentioned that : `To install the PyTorch binaries, you will need to use at least one of two supported package managers: Anaconda and pip`. when I try to install it using `pip` it said that `torch` does not exist.

Comment: @DevProd_ thanks for the note, i will add this to the answer + as i said, torch is not on pypi.org anymore